# Prerequisites for tensor analysis

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, tensors

Suppose that today is my first day as a math undergrad. What are the math classes that I have to take to study tensor analysis?

Some context in case you're wondering.

I am a physics student and my background in math is probably enough for an introduction to tensors (I have already seen them in special rel class) , but I'm not asking for that.
I want to study tensors rigorously as a mathematician would, and for that I'm willing to start relearning math from point zero. I know it's going to take a lot of time (probably a few years), but I have access to lectures and lecture notes from the math department and the patience to learn all the material. Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I understand that my question might be vague, so let's say I just finished
"Roman, advanced linear algebra" and "Vector Calculus by Marsden, Tromba" . How do I move on from there?

Comment: How confident are you with linear algebra?

Comment: Not much, it's been 3 years since I've studied linear algebra and even then, change of basis (which is probably important) was far from my strong point.

Comment: @Loukas : I don't think it takes a few years to learn tensors rigorously. The *Gravitation* book by Misner, Thorne & Wheeler has a lot of "boxes" in which they explain very nicely what the essential difference is between the components of a tensor and the abstract (coordinate free) notation.

Comment: Differential geometry is, in my view, one of the absolute pinnacles of modern mathematics. If you want to relearn mathematics "from point zero", as you say, you have a *long* way to go before you get to this subject, as you correctly said in your post. The key subjects to learn first are multilinear algebra and multivariable calculus. A good understanding of topology and metric spaces is also helpful - open and closed sets, compactness and whatnot.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you mean by tensor analysis? Tensors in physics? Just tensor products of vector spaces, of hilbert spaces, etc.? Numerical tensor stuff? Tensor decompositions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything without knowing **linear algebra**. Tensor algebra comes up with multilinear algebra then tensor calculus. Linear algebra isn't hard much more. Anyone can learn it in less than a week. Actually, in college, we weren't taught geometrical interpretation of linear algebra (saying from around India, not sure of Europe continent or other places). So if you understand the geometry of linear algebra than tensor course will be easy for you. Otherwise it would be much more harder to understand, cause geometry is hardly taught in tensor courses (in most of university, not too much of geometry is taught in tensor course).

**It's more about differential geometry** (if you know vector calculus with geometry than it will be much more easier for you to join tensors).

As someone said in comment, "A good understanding of topology and metric spaces is also helpful". A person (anonymous physicist) told me that don't waste time on learning topology and also said that Einstein had done the whole general relativity without knowing topology.

I believe those who know topology understands differential geometry well, but it takes too much time to learn it (more than a week, a month, almost a year for some, it varies men to men). So better not to waste time on learning it if you are in physics major (learn it later).